# why is 12345 not in the list? and it is the first in the list

Tags: python

```
names=[["Scott","Jones","12345", 9],["Ray","Raymond","67890",8],["Chris","Page","45678", 2],["Chris","Davis","678",10],["Sally","Smoot","90123",5],["Lukas","Flipinski","78901",6],["Anit","Boddu","34567",7],["Janice","Joplin","56789",4]]

search=raw_input("Enter ID here: ")

for i in names:

    if search in i:
        index=names.index(search)

    if names[index][2]<5:
        print "Issue this student a warning"
    else:
        print "Issue this student a detention"
```

### Why is all the number out of list

Answer (score 3):

```
if search in i:
    index=names.index(search)
          ^^^^^

if search in i:
    index=i.index(search)
```

It should be `i` not the `names`.

EDIT:If you want to find index of `names` use

```
if int(search) in i:
    index1=names.index(i)
```

Comment: Im trying to find the index value of search so like whats the index value for the ID# in the name list

Comment: @kobre61385 1)`index` is inbuilt keyword.Do not use it as a variable.2)input type of `raw_input` is string.so use `int(search)` if you want to search for it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
if search in i:
    index=names.index(search)
```

Did you want?

```
if search in i:
    index=i.index(search)
```

Plus you have some other issues, like what if `index` was not found - but that is your business logic I guess.

Comment: thats my question my index is not found >_> but why